# Intersect two layers and get resulting features

Tags: c#, asp.net, arcgis, esri

I have X layers on a map and I need to intersect chosen layers (two per time) and color resulting features.

I'm trying to get this code working

```
// get first feature (index 0)
ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.Geometry adfFeature =
                m_firstLayer.GeometryFromRow(m_firstLayer.Rows[0]) 
as ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.Geometry;

// THE FOLLOWING LINE RETURNS NULL
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry featureInterface = 
    adfFeature as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry;

ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ITopologicalOperator topoOp = 
    adfFeature as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ITopologicalOperator;
```

How to use the IGeometry interface with an ADF Geometry object?

I can't really find samples to intersect features between two layers, and it's a pity that Spatial Joins are just a arcgis desktop function, I surely could use them!

Comment: This question would fit http://gis.stackexchange.com/ well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you use the IGeometry directly. However if you know the specialized type (Point, Polyline, Polygon) you can [convert](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/serveradf_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00020000013s000000) (see the "Web ADF to ArcGIS Server ArcObjects" bullets) to ArcObjects.

You could test what subtype your `ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.Geometry adfFeature` is and do conversion accordingly.

By the way I suggest that you never use the "as" cast since it can fail silently (just returning `null`). Instead I suggest:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry featureInterface = 
    (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry)adfFeature;
```

Then you will see the problem as soon as it occurs.

Comment: Thank you, but I was trying to use the ToIGeometry function and.. I discovered my assembly hasn't it! 

This is weird because the documentation states 10.0 arcgis server adf should have it.. I've posted on the forums here: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/36321-ToIGeometry-function-missing-in-assembly?p=122493#post122493